# Javamail: What is the best way to handle reconnections to a mailserver

Tags: jakarta-mail

I want to check if a mailserver with its services is ready/available. If the mailserver isnt ready the programm should wait for like 5 minutes and should try to connect again Whats missing in Javamail-API is a function to check if a mailserver is ready (or is it not?)

Sure, I can use some ping-mechanisms to check if the server is alive, but what if the server is alive but the mailserverapplication isnt ready yet?

Any good ideas how to implement such reconnect mechanisms?

```
    try {

        store = session.getStore("imaps");

        //If that fails, the programm should try it again in 5 Minutes
        store.connect(imapHost, username, password);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {

        logger.warn("Cant connect to Mailserver: " + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: I solved it already by putting a Thread.sleep() command in the catch part and then just calling the parent - method again. But I am looking for a more elegant way (if there is one)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you want is called "connect".

You can set a property for the connection timeout.  See the javadocs for the various mail protocol providers.